# Writing a best fit line function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I'm using python and scikitlearn for linear regression and visualisation purposes.

Instead of using the `linear_model.LinearRegression()` from `sklearn`, I would need to create my own function to return the gradient and the best-fit line y-intercept.

> m = (μ(x) * μ(y) − μ(x * y))/((μ(x))2 − μ(x2))
>
> b = μ(y) − m * μ(x)

Where μ is a mean function

I am struggling to do this in python.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model


diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()



diabetes_X = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, 2]


diabetes_X_train = diabetes_X[:-20]
diabetes_X_test = diabetes_X[-20:]


diabetes_y_train = diabetes.target[:-20]
diabetes_y_test = diabetes.target[-20:]


regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()


regr.fit(diabetes_X_train, diabetes_y_train)


print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)

print("Mean squared error: %.2f"
      % np.mean((regr.predict(diabetes_X_test) - diabetes_y_test) ** 2))

print('Variance score: %.2f' % regr.score(diabetes_X_test, diabetes_y_test))


plt.scatter(diabetes_X_test,  diabetes_y_test,  color='green', label="Test")
plt.scatter(diabetes_X_train,  diabetes_y_train,  color='red', label ='Training')
plt.plot(diabetes_X_test, regr.predict(diabetes_X_test), color='blue',
     linewidth=3, label='Best fit line')

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use numpy to calculate the mean...

```
import numpy as np

m = (np.mean(x) * np.mean(y) − np.mean(x * y))/((np.mean(x))**2 − np.mean(x**2))
b = np.mean(y) − m * np.mean(x)
```

but send some code you have done to get more specific help !

Comment: thanks I've added code so you can see in context. I believe I need to use the training data for x and y but just not sure on how to fit it in context.

Comment: I think it's first conceptual problem, you should understand better what you are doing....you can find lot of good courses like : https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning